# django: how to make a choice field choosing from entry of a m2m field?

Tags: django, django-models

Sorry if the title doesn't make lots of sense.

Let's say we have a model set up like this:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    sample = models.ManyToManyField(Sample)

class SampleLogoutRecord(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sample_choice = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, choices = SAMPLE_CHOCIES)
    logout_date =  models.DateField(null=True)
    logout_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
```

So basically with have the main model Project which holds a m2m field sample that relates to several samples. And then SampleLogoutRecord is a foreign key to project that is a record of a specific piece of sample belonging to this project is logged out. My problem is, how do I set sample_choice up so that this choice field use those samples belongs to this project as choice options?

For example, if Project A has sample 1, 2 and 3. I would like sample_choice to be a choice field with options: 1, 2 and 3.

From official document it seems that choices of a choice field could be a callable that returns a 2-tuple list. This sounds like what I should do but I got stuck on how actually implements this.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

In your form's init method, populate the choices from the database values:

```
class SampleLogoutRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, project, args, **kwargs):
        super(SampleLogoutRecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sample_choice'].choices = [
            (x.id, x.name) for x in project.sample.all()
        ]
        self.project = project

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Assign the project here """
        logout_record = super(SampleLogoutRecordForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs, commit=False)
        logout_record.project = self.project
        logout_record.save()
        return logout_record

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['sample_choice', 'logout_date', 'logout_by']
```

In your view, instantiate the form with the extra `project` argument, including in the POST request handling bit.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SampleLogoutRecordForm(project, request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
         record = form.save()
         # now do stuff to redirect
else:
    form = SampleLogoutRecordForm(project)
```